# How to get a data-attribute of a select element with javascript

Tags: javascript

i've the following select box

```
<select class="selectpicker display-block tax main-tax" name="my_selectbox_name" multiple="" data-none-selected-text="mytext" >
<option value="my_option_value" data-myid="123">my_text</option>
...
</select>
```

I access to the value in this way

```
response.my_selectbox_name = $('.main select.tax').selectpicker('val');
```

How i can access the data-myid value?

Comment: what is `selectpicker` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has a `.data()` method built in for either getting or setting values for a data attribute. When this [method is provided with a key](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like `.data(key)` it will return the value stored in the data attribute. So for your particular example it would be `.data('myid')`. For data attributes anything after 'data-' is considered the key. So for your `<select data-none-selected-text="mytext">` the key is 'none-selected-text'

But to answer your direct question it looks like this:

`$('.selectpicker option').data('myid')`

Comment: possible selected...
$('.selectpicker option:selected').data('myid')

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

```
1. the way to get value
$("option").attr("data-myid"); // 123
$("option").dataset.myid; // 123
2. the way to set value
$("option").attr("data-myid", "YOUR_VALUE"); // YOUR_VALUE
```